# Why is Pionless Effective Field Theory Preferred in Modeling Nuclei for Fermion Scattering Processes?

Tags: scattering, effective-field-theory, pions

There's a recurring preference for pionless effective field theory in recent papers modeling nuclei for fermion scattering processes (e.g., [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06368)).

Why is pionless effective field theory commonly chosen? How does the exclusion of pions impact the theoretical framework?